# Unity Xml Configuration for Registration by convention

Tags: unity-container

How can I configure Unity to use Registration by convention in my web.config file?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [Automatic Type Lookup](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn507491.aspx#_Automatic_Type_Lookup) documentation.

So you can add an entire assembly or namespace to have all the types in that namespace registered into the container automatically...

```
<unity xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/practices/2010/unity">
    <namespace name="MyApp.Interfaces" />
    <assembly name="MyApp” />
</unity>
```